# I am facing an error which says uncaught exception found (signal SIGABRT) in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xcode8, uncaught-exception

I am just trying to print something when a button is clicked.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func bu(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("click")
    }

}
```

its show error in the console as

> 2017-05-22 18:28:58.751 will it work[24356:1074948] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key button.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110a06b0b **exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010ddcb141 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000110a06a59 -[NSException raise] + 9   3   Foundation
>
>   0x000000010d8e0e8b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] +
>   292   4   UIKit                               0x000000010e431644
>   -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87     5   UIKit                               0x000000010e69e6b9 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109   6
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001109ace8d -[NSArray
>   makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 269    7   UIKit
>
>   0x000000010e69d06f -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1856  8
>
>   UIKit                               0x000000010e437c73
>   -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381   9   UIKit                               0x000000010e438589 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177   10  UIKit
>
>   0x000000010e4388ba -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 195   11 
>   UIKit                               0x000000010e43910a
>   -[UIViewController view] + 27     12  UIKit                               0x000000010e30163a -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] +
>   65    13  UIKit                               0x000000010e301d20
>   -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 294  14  UIKit                               0x000000010e314b6e -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42   15  UIKit
>
>   0x000000010e28e31f -[UIApplication
>   _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4346   16  UIKit                               0x000000010e294584
>   -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1709   17  UIKit                               0x000000010e291793
>   -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 182    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001121065f6
>   __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 24     19  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011210646d
>   -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 186  20  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001121067f6 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] +
>   45    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001109acc01
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001109920cf
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527   23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001109915ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911     24  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000110991016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406     25  UIKit
>   0x000000010e29002f -[UIApplication _run] + 468    26  UIKit
>   0x000000010e2960d4 UIApplicationMain + 159    27  will it work
>   0x000000010d638c17 main + 55  28  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000011199665d start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

I think button is not even connected here is the image:
[image: enter link description here]

Comment: check once outlet name `button` is properly disconnected or not in your `ViewController`

Comment: Check your outlet connection with action.

Comment: Probably you do not bind the action to the `UIButton`.

Comment: can u please suggest me how should i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Narasimha Reddy Please disconnect your button outlet from storyboard.

[image]

Comment: thanks, dude.I updated the question with image link can u please check it am I correct or not

Comment: Yes you are now on right path, Please make a reconnection again.

Comment: thanks bro its working now

Comment: You are always welcome bro. @NarasimhaReddy

Answer (score 0):

Please disconnect your button outlet from storyboard.

Comment: how to disconnect (i am a beginner)

Comment: @Narasimha Reddy - Please see my another comment having attached image.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run without the view connected and don't get an exception, something is wrong. When the UIViewController loads and you try to display it, it uses the view to know what to show. Double check your class and connections. If you don't find the problem, post more information and we'll try to figure it out.

Comment: without any swift code I just tried to run the app which has only the button on the screen even though I am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

The most significant information is

> '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key **button**.'

Looking at your code there is only an action `bu` rather than `button` which is most likely a typo.

So replace

```
@IBAction func bu(_ sender: UIButton)
```

with

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton)
```